# Mysql get latest entry on group by

Tags: mysql, join

I have an entry log of updates of which have different category of updates for each ticket number.
For example

```
|Ticket Number | DateTime    | Update           | Category | 
| I0001        | 2015-07-28  | Spoke to someone | Update   |
| I0002        | 2015-07-28  | Issue started    | Update   | 
| I0002        | 2015-07-27  | Owner changed    | System   | 
| I0002        | 2015-07-26  | Auto Alarm       | System   | 
| I0001        | 2015-07-28  | More affected    | Update   | 
| I0001        | 2015-07-25  | Auto Alarm       | System   |
| I0003        | 2015-07-01  | Assigneed        | Update   |
```

I want it to have a list which shows the last DateTime, Update for each Ticket Number and Category so I will end up with something like this.

```
|Ticket Number | DateTime    | Update           | Category | 
| I0001        | 2015-07-28  | Spoke to someone | Update   |
| I0002        | 2015-07-28  | Issue started    | Update   | 
| I0002        | 2015-07-27  | Owner changed    | System   | 
| I0001        | 2015-07-25  | Auto Alarm       | System   |
| I0003        | 2015-07-01  | Assigneed        | Update   |
```

I've tried a few methods but not come close to getting it done.

Comment: Can you please create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: What is the result for the data in the fiddle?

Comment: is there some kind of ID column which is auto increment in this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**

```
select t2.`Ticket Number`,
t2.`DateTime`,
t2.`Update`,
t2.Category
from
(
   select t.*, 
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rn
   from tableName t, 
   (select @rownum := 0) r
   order by t.`Ticket Number`,`DateTime` desc
)t2
group by t2.`Ticket Number`,Category
having min(t2.rn)
order by t2.`DateTime` desc,t2.`Ticket Number`;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bf84e/10)

Answer (score -1):

```
select `Tickte number`, max(`datetime`), category from `table`
```

This will give you the latest for each ticket and category, if you also include the `update` field you are going to get lots of records for each ticket due to the group by.

If you want a query that will match your result set that you posted, you are going to have to use a sub-select or ranking function to do it.

```
select `Ticket number`
  , max(`datetime`)
  , category
  ,  (select `update` from `table` ts where ts.`ticket number` = t.`ticket number` and ts.category = t.category) as `update`

  from `table` t GROUP BY `Ticket Number`, category,
                 (select `update` from `table` ts where ts.`ticket number` = t.`ticket number` and ts.category = t.category)
```

This is not tested, but should get you what you want.